# Want to match Android TextView background to png color

Tags: android, colors, png, spinner

I'm trying to style an Android Spinner. I understand that the selected item is a TextView displayed on top of a selector background png image which contains the arrow. I've managed to generate the 9 patch images and get everything to display properly.

The only problem is that the color I'm specifying for the the TextView needs to match the background color of the selector png, and it doesn't. I specify the same color code for each, but I'm not sure which is off, or why. Can anyone educate me, and hopefully suggest a way to get them to match?

Here's my style.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.NewProject.Title</item>

    <!-- For the resting Spinner style -->
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
        @style/spinnerSelectionStyle
    </item>

    /!-- For Spinner list item style
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        @style/spinnerItemStyle
    </item>
</style>

<!-- main activity action bar styles -->
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.NewProject.Title" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/logo_with_space_on_right</item>
</style>

<style name="spinnerSelectionStyle">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="spinnerItemStyle">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">#8bc34a</item>
</style>
```

I've got the theme set in my AndroidManifest.xml

This is the code to set up the spinner in OnCreateView:

```
    Spinner listSelector = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_choose_list);
    mListSpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            null,
            new String[] {ChecklistContract.Checklist.COLUMN_NAME },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
            0);
    mListSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    listSelector.setAdapter(mListSpinnerAdapter);
    mListSpinnerLoader = new ChecklistLoader(getActivity(), mListSpinnerAdapter, listSelector);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(ChecklistLoader.CHECKLIST_CURSOR_LOADER, null, mListSpinnerLoader);
    mListSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I'd like to post my png, but it appears I need more reputation to do that.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you tried to get better help from the community.

Comment: See my edit to the original question.